# Why does this code throw an automapping exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an internal user inactivity monitor for work, and I'm using a windows form in conjunction with a topshelf service to do this, the code will write to a RabbitMQ Server and the service will consume the messages and forward them to a database, my code as it stands is throwing an exception with the following error;

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
LogData -> DbLogData
AccessEye.LogData -> AccessEye.DbLogData
```

this is the code for my service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NLog;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using Topshelf;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQ;
using EasyNetQ.Topology;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AccessEye;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LogService
{



    public class WindowsServiceHost : ServiceControl, ServiceShutdown
    {
        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
        {
            using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
            {
                DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

                int t = (int)data.EventType;

                EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

                if (eventType == null)
                {
                    eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                    {
                        Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                        Id = (int)data.EventType
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


                logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
                db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
             public static string GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(Enum value)
        {
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }





        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {

            Program.bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=*****;virtualHost=*****;username=***;password=***").Advanced;

            //var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=*******;virtualHost=******;username=****;password=******").Advanced;
            var queue = Queue.Declare(true, false, true, null);
            var exchange = Exchange.DeclareFanout("UserActivityFanout", true, false, null);
            var exchangeTopic = Exchange.DeclareTopic("UserActivity", true, false, null);
            queue.BindTo(exchange, "#");
            exchange.BindTo(exchangeTopic, "#");
            Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, (msg, messageRecInfo) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var data2 = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
                data2.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.Logon;
                WriteLogDataToDb(data2);


                //AppForm.WriteLogDataToDb(data);
                //Console.WriteLine(msg.Body.UserName + " -- " + msg.Body.ComputerName + " -- " + msg.Body.EventType + " -- " + msg.Body.TeamviewerId);
            }));

            return true;

        }

        public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Logger.Trace("STOP");
            Program.bus.Dispose();
            return true;
        }

        public void Shutdown(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Logger.Trace("SHUTDOWN");
            Program.bus.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

and for the form

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AccessEye;
using System.Linq;
using EasyNetQ;
using EasyNetQ.Topology;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using NLog;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection; 

namespace LogProgram
{

    public partial class AppForm : Form
    {

        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private Screensaver watcher;
        public Inactivity inactivity;
        IAdvancedBus bus;
        IExchange exchange;

        public AppForm()
        {

                InitializeComponent();
                ConfigureForm();

                // todo: should be in setting
                int pollingInterval = 5000;

                inactivity = new Inactivity(pollingInterval);
                inactivity.Inactive += inactivity_Inactive;
                inactivity.Active += inactivity_Active;
                inactivity.InactivityThresholdMs = 5 * 1000; // todo: should be in setting
                inactivity.Start();
                watcher = new Screensaver(pollingInterval);
                watcher.ScreensaverOff += watcher_ScreensaverOff;
                watcher.ScreensaverOn += watcher_ScreensaverOn;
                watcher.Start();
                SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
                SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
                LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
                // todo: connection string should be in setting
                bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;
                exchange = Exchange.DeclareTopic("UserActivity", true, false, null);
                var fanout = Exchange.DeclareFanout("FanoutExchange", true, false, null);
                fanout.BindTo(exchange, new[] { "#" });

        }




        public void ConfigureForm()
        {
            this.Hide();
            TrayDisplayer.Visible = false;
        }

        public static void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
        {
            using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
            {
                DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

                int t = (int)data.EventType;

                EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

                if (eventType == null)
                {
                    eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                    {
                        Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                        Id = (int)data.EventType
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
                db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static string GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(Enum value)
        {
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        private void AppForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        void watcher_ScreensaverOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOn;
            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        void watcher_ScreensaverOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOff;
            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();

            switch (e.Reason)
            {
                case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                    data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Lock;
                    break;
                case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                    data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Unlock;
                    break;
            }

            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        public void PublishLogData(AccessEye.LogData LogData)
        {
            WriteLogDataToDb(LogData);

            if (!bus.IsConnected) return;

            try
            {
                using (var publishChannel = bus.OpenPublishChannel())
                {
                    publishChannel.Publish(exchange, LogData.EventType.ToString(), new Message<LogData>(LogData));
                }
            }
            catch (EasyNetQException)
            {
                //todo: handle
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T instance)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private static T DeSerialize<T>(byte[] data)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            bus.Dispose();
        }

        public void inactivity_Active(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            inactivity.Stop();
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Active;
            PublishLogData(data);
            inactivity.Start();

        }

        public void inactivity_Inactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inactivity.Stop();
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Inactive;
            PublishLogData(data);
            inactivity.Start();
        }

        public void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Logoff;
            PublishLogData(data);
            Logger.Trace("Logged off");
            }



        }


    }
```

LogData Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ProtoBuf;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AccessEye
{


    public class DbLogData : LogData
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? EventTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EventTypeId")]
        public virtual EventType EventTypeTest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the code of LogData, DbLogData classes

Comment: A User Inactivity Monitor. Where do you work!?!

Comment: It's an internal application, we've had a couple of problems with people not picking up the phone, but we don't know who is at their desk and who isn't so I've been asked to make this program for them =] it's not like a rootkit or keylogger, it's just to check if the user is at their desk or not =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you need to create a map before you can use one;

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<LogData, DbLogData>();
```

Comment: Indeed! thankyou very much!!! I've edited your answer as AutoMapper.Mapper worked for me, but Mapper.createmap on its own didn't!

Comment: also, try to instruct the mapper with the ForMember() method

Comment: that' just because you haven't included the Automapper namespace